# json.loads converts decimal points to 'e' in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, floating-point

Here is a response I am getting from server

```
[{"type":"bid","price":0.00000026,"amount":737.15054457,"tid":200001915,"timestamp":1516036570}]
```

I am trying to parse this string into JSON using

```
json_data = json.loads (req.text)
```

However when I try to read the 'price' using `json_data[0]['price']` the output is `2.6e-07`

I tried parsing data as `json_data = json.loads (req.text, parse_float=Decimal)` but still no difference.

Comment: That's how python represents the float value 0.00000026. It has nothing to do with JSON. What exactly is the problem? Are you trying to do something with that number that isn't working?

Comment: You have the right *value*, your issue is only with the *representation when you print it*. Just pick a different format to print it with, like `print(format(json_data['price'], '.8f'))`.

Comment: BTW storing a price as a float may have unpleasant implications if you want penny-perfect computations. Reading the value as a text and constructing a Python Decimal from it may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way python shows floats

```
price = 0.00000026
print(price)
```

outputs: 2.6e-07
you can print it this way if you want to see it normal:

```
print('{0:.8f}'.format(price))
```

ouputs: 0.00000026

Comment: Don't use `'{.:<format>}'.format(object)` when you use `format(object, '<format>')` instead, and save Python the bother of having to parse out the `{.:...}` part of out a string template. See the [`format()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format).

Answer (score 0):

Your value *is* parsed as a Decimal, it's just *shown* in an exponential form because it's more compact:

```
import json
import decimal

>>> x = json.loads('{"a":0.00000000000000026}', parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
>>> repr(x)
"{'a': Decimal('2.6E-16')}"
```

You can see that the precision is preserved, though, unlike with a float:

```
>>> x['a'] + 1
Decimal('1.00000000000000026')
>>> 1 + 2.6e-16
1.0000000000000002
```

So everything works as expected.